# Proof of Equivalence of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A is a subset of the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bijective function. We use the notation $gAg^{−1} = \{g\circ f\circ g^{−1} : f \in A\}$. Prove that $A ≈ gAg^{−1}$.

I know to show equivalence I need to show a bijection from $A$ to $gAg^{−1}$, I'm not sure how to use the given information to start going about this.

Answer (score 1):

A bijection from $A$ to $gAg^{-1}$ is, first of all, a function. Given an element $f$ of $A$, what would the obvious way to define an element of $gAg^{-1}$ be? This defines a function which is obviously surjective; then you need to check that it's injective, which shouldn't be too hard.